# sudo apt-get build-dep python-svn doesn't work on fresh Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, software-installation

```
daniel@beepboop /etc/apt $ sudo apt-get build-dep python-svn
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'pysvn' as source package instead of 'python-svn'
E: Unable to find a source package for python-svn
```

My guess is that this has something to do with my sources.list. Any advice?

Some edits to respond to comments:

Trying to install python:

```
daniel@beepboop ~ $ sudo apt-get install python-svn
[sudo] password for daniel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-svn is already the newest version (1.8.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
```

My sources.list:

```
daniel@beepboop /etc/apt $ more sources.list
    deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.1 _Serena_ - Release amd64 20161213]/ xenial contrib ma
    in non-freedeb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted u
    niverse multiverse
```

This was after making some edits I found. I have since reverted it to the original sources.list:

```
daniel@beepboop /etc/apt/sources.list.d $ more sources.list
deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.1 _Serena_ - Release amd64 20161213]/ xenial contrib ma
in non-free
```

sources.list.d:

```
daniel@beepboop /etc/apt/sources.list.d $ more *
::::::::::::::
google-chrome.list
::::::::::::::
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
::::::::::::::
notepadqq-team-notepadqq-xenial.list
::::::::::::::
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu xenial main
::::::::::::::
official-package-repositories.list
::::::::::::::
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com serena main upstream import backport #id:linux
mint_main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe mul
tiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe m
ultiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe 
multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ xenial partner
```

Comment: Can you actually `apt-get install python-svn`?  `build-dep` will look for -devel packages whilst install will not.  And what about `pysvn` (i.e. what is the build-dep of that)?  That's what APT is telling you to look for.

Comment: Are the `deb-src` lines commented in the files `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Comment: I have added the information the two of you requested. I already installed python-svn, and sources.list does not contain any deb-src lines, which I am guessing is a linux Mint thing?